# How to connect MySql Database from AWS RDS to datastudio

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-rds, looker-studio

I am facing on an issue to connect a MySQL instance from AWS to datastudio. My connection is working well on MySQL Workbench and on Python script. But unfortunately, it does not work when I tried the connection on datastudio.

**Connection at MySQL Workbench:**
[image]

**Connection using Python Script:**
[image]

**Connection on datastudio:**
[image]

Could you please help me to understand why I can't access my db from datastudio if I can access it from other programs?

Comment: For the workbeanch it seems you used ssl. For the sutdio ssl option is not enabled. Maybe this is the reason?

Comment: Have you tried enabling the 'Enable SSL' option? The workbench screenshot shows it is using SSL/TLS.

Comment: have you already solved this problem? As far as I have been able to investigate the problem is due to an incompatibility of datastudio with version 8 of my-SQL

Comment: Yes, in fact datatsudio works only with previous version of MySql <= 5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by doing a downgrade of the MySql Version to the version 5.7